# Need your ideas to automate

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

In my project we have a web based tool where it collects all the exceptions that occur in log. The list of exceptions will be displayed in table and a icon will be displayed in a column to get the stack trace. Some one needs to check all those exceptions and we need to assign to different teams based on the keywords.

Eg : If the stacktrace contains "DB Connection error" it has to be assigned to DB team, if it contains code error like "classcast exception" in particular file then it has to be assigned to individual owning the module. Currently some one has to open each n every row in the table displayed and open the stack trace and do Ctrl + F and if any of those keywords are found assign it to respective team.

We don't have any access to the tool's database and it's web based. I need some good ideas to automate it. Please suggest me with which technology and idea to automate it.

Comment: You can do this but it dependents on how the data is arranged in web page you are using. Can u elaborate how the flow goes and how do u perform actions

Comment: Its a web based tool. First i open the URl in browser and after the page loads, I will supply some date criteria and click on search button. The tool searches and loads the data in HTML table containing exceptions that are stored in DB (to which I dont have any access). Each row of the table has a column team which is a dropdown and a Imagelink. Clicking on the imagelink opens stacktrace in a separate window where we can identify the cause and close the window and select the appropriate team in dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `selenium` + `programming language of your choice` is a good fit (even without a `selenium`).

You need to:

1. download source code of the page containing exceptions table.
   Use any of these: `wget`, `curl`, `selenium`, `urllib for python`, etc.
2. put it into variable and extract exceptions list in convenient to you format.
   Use any `xpath`-powered tool, like `selenium`, `lxml for python`, etc.
3. do your thing with the extracted exceptions list: search for keywords, assign tickets, etc.
   Use `programming language of your choice`.

Comment: So is it like every time I need to download the page source, Since I will be supplying different date criteria. And initially the page loads with basic information in table, there which contains a link and we need to click on that link to get the detailed message and will search for keywords and assign it to team... How can I assign using programming since I dont have access to the tool's DB...

Comment: @Senthilnathan just use selenium and your favorite programming language. Here's the place for you to start from: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#getting-started-with-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can achieve this using selenium.

Following are the steps to follow.

1. Supply date criteria with `type` command to the boxes text boxes element.
2. `click` search button.
3. store the required text in variable using `storeValue(locator, variableName)`.
4. click on image link if you are able to keep track of popup window else you have to use
    `$second=$sel->getAttribute("//html/body/.../a@href");` and now your $second has link address `$sel->openWindow($second,"MyWindow2");`  now select that new window `$sel->selectWindow("MyWindow2");` and do operation of storing required data from the popup.
5. Now agian for selection of previous window use `$sel->selectWindow("null");  // hear $sel is object of selenium (i.e. $this).
6. Select your required option using `select(selectLocator, optionLocator)`.

Use selenium RC for above steps so that you have more manipulation with the data stored and as per requirement operations.

In above steps syntax are of PHPUnit.

Please try the steps may help you.

Regards.